# What is the name of this combinator?

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus, functional-programming, combinatory-logic

I've recently started casually reading into combinatorial logic, and I noticed that a higher-order function that I regularly use is a combinator. This combinator is actually pretty useful (you can use it to define addition on polynomial equations, for example), but I never gave it a decent name. Does anyone recognise this combinator? (ignoring differences in function currying)

```
unknown = function (h, f, g)
    function (x) h( f(x), g(x) )
}
```

In lambda calculus, the fully curried implementation would be
$\lambda h. \lambda f. \lambda g. \lambda x. h (f x) (g x)$. In other words, if $M$ is this mystery combinator, then its defining equation is $M \, h \, f \, g \, x = h \, (f \, x) \, (g \, x)$.

If more information is needed, or my question is lacking key information please leave a comment and I will edit my question.

Comment: In terms of common combinators, $M h f g = S (B h f) g$ ($B$ is the function composition combinator). I don't know if this has a name, there are lots of combinators out there.

Comment: In Haskell, it is known as `liftM2`. This function lifts `a -> b -> c` to `m a -> m b -> m c`, where `m` is any monad (such as `r ->` in this case) and is extremely useful in many places.

Comment: liftM2 is a valid name, so if you promote this comment to an answer I'll accept it. Funny, my stopgap name was very close; I called the combinator 'binarylift' :)

Comment: This isn't exactly 'professional', but Smullyan's name for this in _To Mock A Mockingbird_ is the _Phoenix_, $\Phi xyzw=x(yw)(zw)$, and he derives it as $\Phi = B(BS)B$; searching on 'Phi combinator' doesn't seem to turn up anything useful, though, so I suspect that name is non-standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't probably a standard name, but in [The Implementation of Functional Programming Languages](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/slpj-book-1987/) in Section 16.2.4 Simon Peyton Jones calls it `S'`. It is defined as an optimization combinator

```
S (B x y) z = S' x y z
```

The following example is from the mentioned section. Consider

```
λx_n...λx_1.PQ
```

where `P` and `Q` are complicated expression that both use all the variables.
Eliminating lambda abstractions leads to quadratic increase of term sizes in `n`:

```
P Q
S P1 Q1
S (B S P2) Q2
S (B S (B (B S) P3)) Q3
S (B S (B (B S) (B (B (B S)) P4))) Q4
```

etc., where `Pi` and `Qi` are some terms. With the help of `S'` this gets only linear:

```
P Q
S P1 Q1
S' S P2 Q2
S (S' S) P3 Q3
S (S' (S' S)) P4 Q4
```